# Infinite self-convolution of unit box, and convergence to normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

A very generic unit box, convoluted with itself n times and letting n increase towards infinity. Does it converge to a normal distribution? And, is there a specific type of unit box that would convolve to a standard normal distribution? Perhaps when it is 1 for x = -0.5 to 0.5?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm unsure but I would guess no. The reason is that if you assume differentiating results in differentiating one of the unit boxes (which is what happens with finite convolutions) then you should get a linear combination of two shifts of a gaussian. However the derivative of a $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is not a linear combination of shifts of itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Central limit theorem (CLT), sum of i.i.d random variables (with same PMF), the unit box is a PMF (same as continuous uniform distribution), and the CLT assumes the equivalent of self-convolution (since variables are identically distributed, i.e., have the same PMF. ) Therefore, sum of unit box (convolutions of it) should converge to normal distribution?

Comment: Let $B_k$ denotes a unit box convoluted with itself $k$ times. I assumed you were asking whether $B_k(x) \to_k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}$ point-wise for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm a beginner at all this. I am trying to learn, get a bit picture overview of, phenomena of convergence to gauss curve. I felt a bit of an "aha moment" when I saw the self-convolution of simple square, into triangle, then a bell shape. I was wondering if the example I saw by definition converges to a normal distribution. I don't see why it would not, since it conforms to CLT as far as I see.